# How to read data from MS Access using Android SDK?

Tags: android, ms-access, odbc

I have a 20-year old database in MS Access and am trying to develop an Android application based on that DB. Please explain if this is possible and which method I should use to connect/read the DB.
As far as I know, ODBC is not supported in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the db schema and then translate the queries into SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to convert to to a SQLite database.

http://code.google.com/p/mdb-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [more here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136101.html). It should work very similarly to how you would do it running Java on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your are quite correct - ODBC is not supported via Android - and as CrackerJack9, kind of, states - JDBC is!!!

So, you could consider a [JDBC to ODBC Bridge](http://download.openlinksw.com/solwiz/wizard.php?uda_step1_radio=1&client_application=14&client_language=1&client_interface=1&client_opsys_family=26&client_opsys=jvm-sun-java1.5-32&server_dbms_family=9999&server_dbms=access&server_opsys_family=1&server_opsys=i686-generic-win-32&enterprise_level=0&dbms_server_install=2) ...